# For some $X\in \Gamma TM$, does there exist a parallel transport that preserves it?

Tags: differential-geometry, connections

Given a nowhere vanishing vector field $X\in\Gamma TM$ on a smooth manifold $M$, is it always possible to find a connction $\nabla$ on $M$ so that the parallel transport induced by $\nabla$ preserves $X$?

By this, I mean that given some smooth curve $\gamma:[0,1]\longrightarrow M$, and denoting the parallel transport from $\gamma(0)$ to $\gamma(t)$ along $\gamma$ by $P^\gamma_{0,t}$, one has
$$P^\gamma_{0,t}(X) = X(\gamma(t))$$ for all $t\in[0,1]$.

My initial guess would be that this should be possible at least locally using first local frames and then a partition of unity for the whole manifold, but on the other hand it seems to be too strong of a statement.

Comment: I have two suggestions: 1) Test this on $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the standard flat metrics. 2) Try to prove it yourself. Using a local frame or local coordinates is fine but not necessarily needed.

Comment: What does the Riemannian metric have to do with the question?

Comment: @JackLee I am very honoured that you commented on my question – and the mentioning of the metric is only a residue of how I formulated the question differently before.

Comment: One caveat: What happens when $X$ vanishes at a point $p$, but not everywhere?

Comment: @kajelad thanks, I see your point. However, in my case, one can exclude that possibility

Comment: OK, with the added assumption that $X$ never vanishes, your intuition is correct. Why don't you write it up and answer your own question?

Comment: Given that you don’t want a Riemannian connection, I am changing tags.

Comment: @JackLee Now that I have thought about it: Would it suffice to just define the connection by choosing any horizontal bundle that contains $X$?

Comment: @Nuke_Gunray: Not sure what you mean by "horizontal bundle" in this context. A connection in $TM$ can be viewed as a horizontal subbundle of $T(TM)$; but the values of $X$ are not elements of this "second tangent bundle."

Comment: @JackLee you're right. I just thought about using the projection map (or rather its inverse) somehow. Then what about using $X$ to construct a local frame (e.g. by using a local trivialization and rotating $X$ by some angle in each coordinate direction) and then define the parallel transport by the property that it preserves $X$, acts somehow on the other basis vectors, and is then extended linearly to all of the fiber?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is true. Choose a Riemannian metric  $g$ and a connection $\nabla$ on $M$. Then $X$ is parallel for the connection $\bar\nabla$ which for $Y,Z\in\Gamma TM$ is defined by
$$\bar\nabla_ZY:=\nabla_ZY-g(X,Y)/g(X,X)\,\nabla_ZX$$

Comment: Thank you very much!